# Saving object relationships in Moshi

Tags: java, json, moshi

I'd like to save the relationship between two json structures while parsing them with Moshi.

Lets say there exists the following situation:

I would like to parse this json structure:

```
refrigerator: {
  ... ,
  manufacturer: "GE",
  items: [{name: "apple", name: "pear"...}]
}
```

I have the following model classes, written in psudo-java:

```
class Refrigerator {
  public ArrayList<Item> items;
  ...
}

class Item {
  public String name;
}
```

How can I make it so that `Item` contains a reference back to it's `Refrigerator`, or at least that `Refrigerator`'s name?

I've though about implementing this behavior with a Moshi `Adapter`, but I can't quite figure out how it would work.
Is there some way to modify a `Refrigerator` right after it has been deserialized, and touch each of its `items`?

Comment: Do you also want a recursive reference to the Item? (Item with a reference to Refrigerator with a reference to a list that contains the item.)

Comment: Either a reference to a `Refrigerator` or the value `RefrigeratorName`.